# What are the advantages of having a game loop implemented as a function?

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I learned that functions should perform a well-defined **action** and should be named  according to what they do. For example, a function that adds its two arguments could be written:

```
def adder(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2
```

Here, *adder* has a **well-defined role** and its name says exactly what it **does**. Now, if a game loop was implemented as a function:

```
def mainloop(fps):

    while True:
        # DO STUFF
        tick(fps)
```

would it still be right to say that the function is doing something and has a well-defined role? If so, what exactly are the advantages of implementing the loop as a function instead  of leaving it in the global scope?

Answer (score 2):

Due to an implementation detail, the same code in a function can run faster than when it is in the global namespace.

Comment: This is true, but I believe it isn't an issue in pygame's mainloop since all the other operations take a much bigger amount of time then global lookup vs local lookup.

Comment: Besides, the call site of `tick` is already inside a function (`gameloop`).

Answer (score 1):

It would still be good form to have your loop outside of a function, there is nothing wrong with that. For one of my own pygame projects, I had to do that because otherwise there was scoping issues. An advantage of putting it into a function is that you could potentially access it from another python file:

```
from game import mainloop

mainloop(65)
```